# Passing the Class Type instead of the Interface through Generics

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

OK I've just implemented a Command-CommandHandler pattern in our application that adds a command object to a queue; then uses dependency injection through Castle Windsor alongside a generic method to get the relevant handler for the command object.

The Command interface is blank like so:

```
public interface ICommand
{
}
```

Whilst the CommandHandler interface handles it like so:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

These are then implemented by the commands I wish to send through the queue; then registered in Castle Windsor through a DependencyRegistration wrapper like so:

```
_dependencyRegister
    .AddRegistration<ICommandHandler<TestCommand>, TestCommandHandler>();
```

So each command that will be added to the queue maps 1 to 1 with a handler; then is registered in Castle Windsor; so we can use a generic method like this to get the relevant CommandHandler for a particular Command object:

```
private void HandleCommand<T>(T queueItem) where T: ICommand
{
    var handler = _dependencyResolver.Resolve<ICommandHandler<T>>();

    handler.Handle(queueItem);
}
```

The final piece is the queue dispatcher method which looks like this:

```
private void DispatchQueueItem(ICommand queueItem)
{
    HandleCommand(queueItem);
}
```

Right; the issue is that when I pull a command off the queue as an ICommand and pass it to the DispatchQueueItem method; when it is sent to the HandleCommand method the "T" type is always set to the "ICommand" interface; rather than the actual implementation of the interface (TestCommand in the DependencyRegistration sample code).

My question is; how do I set the HandleCommand method to take the Type of the implementation; not the interface?

Comment: One second for me to duplicate this generic setup. I suspect because `DispatchQueueItem` boxes as `ICommand`, that the generic argument to `HandleCommand` is inferred from the boxed type.

Comment: The of(T) generic construct is a compile time resolution of the type. You are looking for run time type resolution. You will have to use the dynamic type, or reflection to determine that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your dispatch method to generic:

```
private void DispatchQueueItem<T>(T queueItem)
    where T: ICommand
{
    HandleCommand(queueItem);
}
```

UPDATE you can force C# to define object type at runtime this way

```
private static void DispatchQueueItem(ICommand queueItem)
{
    HandleCommand((dynamic)queueItem);
}
```

Comment: OK I've changed the calling method to also use generics'; however I'm still getting the issue.  If it helps; the method which retrieves the ICommand items before passing to the DispatchQueueItem method looks like this: `public IEnumerable<ICommand> Dequeue()`

Comment: You're seven shades of a legend; that's it, using dynamic forces the item to resolve to the implemented Type rather than the interface

Answer (score 0):

I think you *want* it to be of the interface - but you just need to have a method contract defined in there - like:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

//Concrete implementation:
public TestCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Then, when you get the ICommand out of DI - you can call `queueItem.Execute()` - and this will refer to whatever concrete implementation you've assigned.

Comment: Fair point; however I want to maintain the integrity of the Command - CommandHandler pattern as outlined here: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91.  The way you have described is certainly easier; however the above article should explain why the separation is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yout queue will lalways dispatch ICommands. So so need to get the type "under the hood":

```
private void HandleCommand<T>(T queueItem) where T: ICommand
{
  var typeParam = queueItem.GetType();
  var type = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(typeParam);
  var handler = _dependencyResolver.Resolve(type);
```

I'm not sure of the exact sintax. Don't have a project with Castle Windsor at hand.

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer there; however when I add `.Resolve(type)` or `Resolve<type>` or `Resolve<ICommandHandler<type>>` I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'type'"

Comment: Can you debug and see what type is `type`? i.e. get `type.FullName`. And also the type of `queueItem`.